# Good Terminal program for windows

Tags: windows, terminal

I'm growing a little sick of Microsoft's HyperTerminal,

Can anyone recommend a good terminal program (that accepts com connections)?

Preferably free.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) ?

[replace windows vista hyper terminal with PuTTY](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/replace-windows-vista-hyperterminal-with-putty.html)

Comment: Putty is definitely a favorite!

Comment: I use PuTTY to interact with my Arduino board as a serial terminal, and to connect to my webhost's FreeBSD system. It's a great program. I recommend PuTTY Tray: http://haanstra.eu/putty/ it has some nice enhancements over the original version.

Comment: FTW I have putty for other things i didn't know it had a com setting till you said. thanks

Answer (score 6):

There are many HyperTerminal alternatives around. Here are some of them:

Tera Term has forked into:
[TeraTerm Pro Web 3.1.3](http://www.ayera.com/teraterm/) : Enhanced Telnet/SSH2 Client
[sourceforge.jp](http://sourceforge.jp/projects/ttssh2/) : Open-source project

[HyperTerminal Private Edition version 7.0](http://www.hilgraeve.com/hyperterminal.html)
Terminal emulation program that supports communications over TCP/IP networks, Dial-Up Modems, and serial COM ports.

[Poderosa.org](http://en.poderosa.org/)
Poderosa is a tabbed terminal emulator for Windows.

[Realterm](http://realterm.sourceforge.net/)
A terminal program specially designed for capturing, controlling and debugging binary and other difficult data streams. It is far better for debugging comms than Hyperterminal. It has no support for dialing modems, BBS etc - that is what hyperterminal does.

Comment: I love TeraTerm because of its ability to incorporate macros. They really come in handy when you're in a crunch and need to gather info or make changes en masse.